# Displaying a Google Chart only when data is present

Tags: javascript, function, charts, call

I have a Google Line Chart that uses SQL data. However, when 0 rows are returned by the query, it displays a big empty chart on the page. I would like to instead display some text saying that there is no data. I tried wrapping the chart functions inside another function that I call if data is present, but nothing was displayed, even if the data was present. Here is some of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
function displayChart()
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    });
}
function drawChart() 
{
// Here we tell it to make an ajax call to pull the data from the .json file
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "Data.json",
    dataType:"json",
    async: false
}).responseText;

// Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

// Options for the graph, we set chartArea to get rid of extra whitespace
var options = {
                'width':1300,
                'height':500,
                'chartArea': {top:'10%', left:'5%', height:'75%', width:'85%'}
              };

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options and putting it in the chart_div.
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data,options); 
}
</script>
<?

...

if($got_data == true)
{
    displayChart();
}
else
    echo "There is no data";
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong, or a better way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: how and where is the value of $got_data set?

Comment: Use callback of $.ajax instead of synchronous call

Comment: @Vishal Kumar $got_data is set to true after the sql query if 1 or more rows are returned. I have checked and this works correctly

Answer (score 0):

As Serg's comment says, you need to set whether display your chart in a callback from your ajax call.  This is because the data that will be returned from your ajax call is not present nor accessible when you call `$.ajax()`.  If you look down on the [JQuery AJAX page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you will see several examples of how to deal with your data from the ajax call, but what you are looking for will be something like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Data.json",
    dataType:"json",
    async: false
}).complete(function(data) {
    if (data) {
        // draw chart
    } else {
        // say no data
    }
);
```

Comment: But the ajax call is inside the drawChart function. I would have to call the drawChart function from within the drawChart function? I am aware of recursive functions but I'm not sure this will work

Comment: it should be something like `getChartData` which contains the ajax call, then the ajax complete function would call the `drawChart` function